# Oracle: Finding rowIds of records modified by a particular transaction

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In our production system, we are using *Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition*. I am  currently facing a situation where I have the Transaction ID of the transaction that modified some records of a particular table. I need to find these modified records.

After a lot of googling, the only leads I have are related to flashback data. Namely the *FLASHBACK_TRANSACTION_QUERY* table or the *VERSIONS_XID* of the flashback version of the modified table. The problem is that these transaction IDs do not match. For example, the transaction ID that I get are of the form '*11.18.823626*' and the ones in VERSIONS_XID are of the form '*29001E00697F0000*'

Is there any way I can find the rowids (or other column data) of the rows modified by a given transaction given it's transaction id?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hextoraw()` function to cast the `VERSIONS_XID` identifier to `FLASHBACK_TRANSACTION_QUERY.XID`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But it doesn't seem to be working for me. For e.g. the if I call `hextoraw()` on '_05001B0027510300_' it gives me the same string as output. The transaction ID which I get is '_5.27.217383_' and the one in the VERSIONS_XID is '_05001B0027510300_'. I am unable convert one to get the other.